# collect an array in nested property without using concat apply

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have nested array within array, how to get checked's id?

```
[{
    no: 1,
    car: [{
        id: 123,
        name: 'abc'
    },{
        id: 456,
        name: 'def',
       checked: true
    }]
}]
```

So in this case it's `['456']`, but how to do it with es6 and without using concact.apply or mutating variable using push method?

Comment: lodash: `_(data).flatMap('car').filter('checked').map('id').value()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results by using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of cars, [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) go get the checked cars, and then mapping to `id`. The current result is an array of arrays.

To flatten the results in ES6, you can spread into concat, instead of applying it.

```js
const data = [{"no":1,"car":[{"id":123,"name":"abc"},{"id":456,"name":"def","checked":true}]}]

const result = [].concat(...data
  .map((o) => o.car
    .filter(o => o.checked)
      .map(o => o.id)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods.

```js
var data = [{
  no: 1,
  car: [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 456,
    name: 'def',
    checked: true
  }]
}];


console.log(
  data[0].car.filter(o => o.checked).map(o => o.id)
)
```

**UPDATE 1:** Generalized solution with multiple elements using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var data = [{
  no: 1,
  car: [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 456,
    name: 'def',
    checked: true
  }]
}, {
  no: 1,
  car: [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 345,
    checked: true
  }]
}];


console.log(
  data.reduce((arr, d) => {
    [].push.apply(arr, d.car.filter(o => o.checked).map(o => o.id));
    return arr;
  }, [])
)
```

**UPDATE 2:** You can avoid [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method by using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) but I don't think it's an elegant way.

```js
var data = [{
  no: 1,
  car: [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 456,
    name: 'def',
    checked: true
  }]
}, {
  no: 1,
  car: [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 345,
    checked: true
  }]
}];


console.log(
  data.reduce((arr, d) => [...arr, ...d.car.filter(o => o.checked).map(o => o.id)], [])
)

// or with spread with push, which would be better alternative
console.log(
  data.reduce((arr, d) => (arr.push(...d.car.filter(o => o.checked).map(o => o.id)), arr), [])
)
```

Comment: You're not working with the nested array, you're explicitly selecting the first element (`data[0]`).

Comment: The question was too ambiguous to gain a definitive answer.  His answer made as much sense as any

Comment: @aaaaaa What's ambiguous about the question? It clearly mentions nested array in array. OP is looking for a `flatMap` implementation without using `concat.apply()` or looping and pushing results in another array. What's ambiguous about that?

Comment: You clearly understand the schema of the object they're working with and want as a result.  Oh wait...

Comment: The updated answer uses `push()` to mutate a variable which was specified as unwanted in the question.

Comment: a flat map of an anonymous array containing an inner array of `car` eh?  Glad you're able to make sense of that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in my opinion.
When ever i need to `filter` and `map` an array, i immediately try to do it with `reduce`, so i can reduce the number of loops i need to do over the array.

With `reduce` you can conditionally `push` an object to the [accumulator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters) (This is like doing the filtering)
And when you push it, you can decide the shape of the object you want to push (This is like doing the mapping).

Using `push` in this case is OK, because you are mutating a local array and not the external one.

Here is an example of such use case:

```js
var data = [{
  no: 1,
  car: [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 456,
    name: 'def',
    checked: true
  }]
}];

const nextData = data.reduce((result, current) => {
    const flatten = current.car.reduce((r,c) => {
      if(c.checked){ // filter
        r.push(c.id); // map
      }
      return r;
    },[]);
    result.push(...flatten);
    return result;
  }, [])

console.log(nextData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `filter` and `map`

```js
var data = [{
  no: 1,
  car: [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 456,
    name: 'def',
    checked: true
  }, {
    id: 69,
    name: 'ford',
    checked: true
  }]
}];

var ids = data[0].car.filter(c => c.checked).map(c => c.id)
console.log(ids)
```